# Perl Cannot Binmode STDOUT After Untie Filehandle

Tags: perl, stdout, filehandle, tie, binmode

I need to disable progressive buffering of an HTTP response.

I've got this working in Perl using a file handle class:

```
$|=1;
$TIE = tie(*STDOUT,__PACKAGE__);
```

Print statements are stored in an array and are retrieved via the following:

```
$buffer = tied *STDOUT;
$buffer = join('', @$buffer);
undef $TIE;
untie(*STDOUT);
```

If the HTTP response is `text/html`, it correctly displays in the browser.

However, for binary streams, I can't set `binmode` on `STDOUT` after it is untied, and the contents are corrupted.

If I save the HTTP response to a file, or if I do not use a file handle class, the binary data is preserved.

Any suggestions on how to force raw encoding? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this work?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Handle;

my $io = IO::Handle->new;
my $fh = $io->fdopen(fileno(STDOUT),"w");
$fh->autoflush(1);

my $TIE = tie( $fh ,__PACKAGE__);

sub TIESCALAR { };

binmode($fh);

print $fh "Foo";
```

Comment: Thanks, Evan. I've narrowed it down to my chunked transfer encoding method which is using `unpack` with an `a` template. That seems to be overriding `binmode`.